# Building complex report with t-sql, each row has its own where condition

Tags: t-sql, optimization, sql-server-2012

I am building one complex report with T-SQL. User gave me the table that is **source for the report** and has about 10 milion rows. Table contains descriptive attributes and numeric columns, something like this:

segment product_group  gmis  lpt  numeric_field1 numeric_field2 numeric_field3

Report have about thousand rows, and **the definition of the report** goes row by row something like this:

'Name of the row one'  - sum of the numeric_field1 for segment in 3,4,5 and lpt = 3 and gmis <> 50

'Row number two' - sum of num2 for segment in 1,2,3 and lpt <> 5, and gmis = 7

'Row number 3' - you take num2 + num3 for product_id = 7

'Row number 4' - row 1 + row 2

So I end up with t-sql query that have separate select for each row followed by union all:

```
'Row number 1' name, (select sum(num1) from source_table where segment in (3,4,5) and lpt=3 and gmis <> 50) value
union
'Row number 2'  , (select sum(num2) from source_table where segment in (1,2,3) and lpt<> 5 and gmis = 7) 
union
'Row number 3' , (select sum(num2 + num3) from source_table where product_id = 7)
```

.....
....
etc

Am I missing some smarter way to do this kind of query?? Because the report is very slow....

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. For example, in recent versions of SQL Server a common table expression (CTE) might be applicable to avoid repeating some of the queries.

Comment: I have just added sql server 2012 is in question....

Comment: Not really an answer, but in the sample above you use "UNION" instead of "UNION ALL"; I just wanted to be sure that it was a typo in the sample but not the code.  Even on UNION statement will cause a DISTINCT search over your query, which can be a big performance hit.

Comment: @Stuart Ainsworth: you're wright, all the time I was thinking about union all but wrote union in the query (not just in this example, but in query itself... Thank you, this is first step forward :). But I wanted somehow to entirelly avoid writing new query for each row if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are always selecting from the same base table and always aggregating without grouping, the following should suit your purpose.

1. Instead of combining multiple selects, you should aim to perform a set of operations on a single table.  Take your where clauses and combine them into a select statement as a set of when clauses to calculate the base values used for aggregation.  This means that you only have to read the source table once:

   ```
   Select
       Case When segment in (3,4,5) and lpt = 3 and gmis <> 50 Then num1 Else 0 End As row1,
       Case When segment in (1,2,3) and lpt<> 5 and gmis = 7 Then num1 Else 0 End As row2,
       Case When product_id = 7 then (num2+num3) Else 0 End As row3
   From
       source_table
   ```
2. Use this as a table expression and perform the aggregation selecting from the table expression.  In this example, I have used a CTE (Common Table Expression):

   ```
   ;With Column_Values
   (
       row1,
       row2,
       row3
   )
   As
       (
           Select
               Case When segment in (3,4,5) and lpt = 3 and gmis <> 50 Then num1 Else 0 End As row1,
               Case When segment in (1,2,3) and lpt<> 5 and gmis = 7 Then num1 Else 0 End As row2,
               Case When product_id = 7 then (num2+num3) Else 0 End As row3
           From
               source_table
       )
   Select
       name,
       value
   From
       (
           Select
               Sum(row1) As [Row number 1],
               Sum(row2) As [Row number 2],
               Sum(row3) As [Row number 3],
               Sum(row1) + Sum(row2) As [Row number 4]
           From
               Column_Values
       )
   ```
3. You now have the values as a series of columns.  To convert them to rows, use the unpivot command:

   ```
   ;With Column_Values
   (
       row1,
       row2,
       row3
   )
   As
       (
           Select
               Case When segment in (3,4,5) and lpt = 3 and gmis <> 50 Then num1 Else 0 End As row1,
               Case When segment in (1,2,3) and lpt<> 5 and gmis = 7 Then num1 Else 0 End As row2,
               Case When product_id = 7 then (num2+num3) Else 0 End As row3
           From
               source_table
       )
   Select
       name,
       value
   From
       (
           Select
               Sum(row1) As [Row number 1],
               Sum(row2) As [Row number 2],
               Sum(row3) As [Row number 3],
               Sum(row1 + row2) As [Row number 4]
           From
               Column_Values
       ) pvt
   Unpivot
       (
           value For name In
               (
                   [Row number 1],
                   [Row number 2],
                   [Row number 3],
                   [Row number 4]
               )       
       ) As upvt
   ```

If you are still having performance issues, there are the following options you may wish to consider, which will depend on your requirements:

•   If you don't need to report live data you could pre-calculate the values, store them in another table and report from this table.

•   If you have the Enterprise edition and don't need to report live data, you could put a columnstore index on the source table - in SQL Server 2012 this makes the table read only, so it would have to dropped and recreated each time new data is loaded into the source table.  Columnstore indexes can offer a massive performance boost when aggregating large tables.

•   If you need to report live data, you can use an indexed view.  This may improve performance when aggregating data in the view.